# Determinar la cantidad de usuarios logueados en el sistema web

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Estoy utilizando devise para el manejo de sesiones en mi aplicación. Queria saber de que manera puedo realizar un count de la cantidad de usuarios logueados en mi web.

Ruby v.2.6.3
Rails v.5.2.4

Comment: Recuerda agregar algo que lleves hecho apra evitar el cierre de tu pregunta

Comment: Hola franco, las preguntas pidiendo recomendaciones de libros, tutoriales, plugins, etc. se consideran como muy amplias y basadas en opiniones y nos e ajustan bien al formato y contenido del sitio. Lee [ask] y [¿Sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](/help/on-topic) para más información.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar `Active Record Session Store` donde básicamente haces lo siguiente:
1.  Crear la migración para guardar las sesiones

```
rake db:sessions:create
```

2. Agregar la siguiente linea en `config/initializers/session_store.rb`

```rb
YourApplication::Application.config.session_store :active_record_store
```

3. Si deseas saber el numero de usuarios logeados en el sistema, con el siguiente comando:

```rb
ActiveRecord::SessionStore::Session.count
```

Espero te ayude en algo

Comment: Muchas gracias, voy a intentar con eso. Para imprimir en pantalla 'ActiveRecord::SessionStore::Session.count' como lo haría?

Comment: Esto funciona para rails 5?